# powershell scheduled job fails to run

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a scheduled job using windows powershell, but it can not run correctly.
I check the taskschd.msc and run the job through GUI. And the result is like this "System can not find specified file"(My system is in Chinese language and I translate the result message).
Here is the command I use:

```
$T = New-JobTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)
Register-ScheduledJob -Name Test -Trigger $T -ScriptBlock {shutdown.exe /h}
```

Another question is I have imported module PSScheduledJob, but I cannot track scheduled job information by using command `Get-Job`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scheduled tasks and scheduled jobs are different things. if I understand you right you want to create a scheduled task (which can also be managed using `taskschd.msc`). this can be done as follows:

```
#create a task action
$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'shutdown.exe' -Argument '/h'
#create a task trigger
$taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)
#register scheduled task with actionn and trigger
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'hibernate computer' -Action $taskAction -Trigger $taskTrigger
```

after registering the scheduled task you can also see/edit in using `taskschd.msc`

Comment: I have checked the difference between scheduled task and scheduled job. Thank you for your help.